# Swift - Default Implementation of protocol functions in another protocol

Tags: ios, swift, protocols

The following code is just an example:
I need to implement `MapProtocol` in my ViewController class. The ViewController itself has a variable of type `MKMapView`. However in my case the `MKMapViewDelegate` needs to be implemented by an extension of the protocol and cannot be implemented by the ViewController class, but this does not work. The delegate function won't be called at all (only if implemented by the ViewController)

Am I missing a swift restriction for adding default implementations for protocols within another protocol? If yes, is there are proper workaround?

Real case scenario:
I have two ViewControllers which share some redundant code (MKMapViewDelegate, etc). So I wanted to outsource this code. I can’t use a superclass because both of the viewcontrollers are already subclasses of two different Types. My first approach was to use an extended protocol.

```
import UIKit
import MapKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, MapProtocol {

    var mapView: MKMapView = MKMapView()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        setupMapView()
    }

    private func setupMapView() {
        self.view.addSubview(mapView)

        mapView.mapType = MKMapType.standard
        mapView.isZoomEnabled = true
        mapView.isScrollEnabled = true
        mapView.delegate = self

        mapView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        mapView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        mapView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        mapView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        mapView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.trailingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    }
}

/** Works if uncommented */
//extension ViewController: MKMapViewDelegate {
//    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, regionWillChangeAnimated animated: Bool) {
//        NSLog("test")
//    }
//}

protocol MapProtocol: MKMapViewDelegate {
    var mapView: MKMapView { set get }
}

extension MapProtocol {
    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, regionWillChangeAnimated animated: Bool) {
        NSLog("test")
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `MapProtocol` exactly and why must `MKMapViewDelegate` be in a protocol extension?

Comment: It‘s just a sample code. Unfortunately I cannot use a different approach (e.g subclassing)

Comment: But what is `MapProtocol`? And what do you mean when you say `MKMapViewDelegate` must be in a protocol extension? In your code, it's in a view controller extension; is that what you mean?

Comment: I edited the question and provided some real case info. Maybe it‘s a bit more clear now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understood the question correctly, you want to avoid repeating "map related code" in different viewcontroller.

In such a case, why not having a "data source" approach, create an additional class `ViewControllerMapInjector` or whichever name, and in the initialization pass both the vc and execute whatever method you prefer

```
class ViewControllerMapInjector: MKMapViewDelegate {
    private let vc: UIViewController
    init(vc: UIViewController) {
       self.vc = vc
    }

    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, regionWillChangeAnimated animated: Bool) {
        NSLog("test") // or use the vc as you want. 
    }
}
```

then in the viewController `setup()` just

`self.mapView.delegate = ViewControllerMapInjector(vc: self)`

Eventually you may need to apply additional patterns to the view controller to let additional methods be visible to the provider if needed (in the end the simplest solution is to go full OO and subclass the ViewController). It's a bit convoluted, but the alternative i can think of are not much simpler.

Comment: It‘s just a simple example to explain the problem. I cannot provide the real code. 
I just want to know if it‘s possible to implement protocol functions in an extended protocol or if there is a nice workaround :)

Answer (score 1):

That's a bit of a strange case but I don't think the dispatch lookup for the delegate is going to "see" the delegate method when added by the protocol. Protocol extensions are statically bound and not part of the dynamic lookup scheme.

Comment: I provided some info about the real case scenario because the code shown here is just an example. Do you have any tips on how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

if you are thinking that `func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, regionWillChangeAnimated animated: Bool)` is a MKMapViewDelegate protocol method then it is wrong. it is just method which is created by you not a MKMapViewDelegate method.

```
extension MapProtocol {

    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, regionWillChangeAnimated animated: Bool) {
        NSLog("test")
    }
}
```

same is reason that your delegate method is not calling. Callback is received by viewController because  `mapView.delegate = self`. Here it is no role of MapProtocol.